# vb .net custom control property not saved at runtime

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I declared a custom property "Padding"

```
    Public Overloads Property Padding() As Padding
    Get
        Return (pad)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As Padding)
        pad = Value
        RecalculateCharacterSize()
        Me.Refresh() 
    End Set
End Property
```

and works at design time. But when I run the form, this property is reset to 0 and when come back in design editor is also zero. There is a conflict with originally "Padding" property name because if I change to "Padding2" works fine (and I can change my name) but the originally name fits best :)

Thanks very much for suggestions, I'm sure there is something stupid here

PS. I decored with those but still nothing works

```
<EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), Browsable(True), Bindable(True), _
DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)> _
```

any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just trying to add to the existing `Padding` Property try something like this.

```
Public Shadows Property Padding() As Padding
    Get
        Return (MyBase.Padding)

    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As Padding)
        MyBase.Padding = Value
        pad = Value
        RecalculateCharacterSize()
        Me.Refresh()
    End Set
End Property
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks very much Mark, works :)

```
Public Shadows Property Padding() As Padding
    Get

        Return (pad)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As Padding)
        pad = Value
        MyBase.Padding = pad ' ---> this had to be added 
        RecalculateCharacterSize()
        Me.Refresh()
    End Set
End Property
```